# How to compare the String value of a [[String]] to a String?

Tags: swift, multidimensional-array

I want to be able to compare values from the `[String]` level instead of the `String` level. Here's what I mean:

```
var connectedNames:[[[String]]] = [[[]]]

for var row: Int = 0; row < connectedNames[0].count; row++ {
    if self.connectedNames[0][row] as! String == "asdf" {

    }
}
```

But the cast here from `[String]` to `String` fails so I can't make this value comparison.

So the main problem is this: Is there anyway to compare the String value of a `[[String]]` to a `String`? In other words, the String value that I get from indexing `connectedNames` like so `connectedNames[0][0] == "Some String"`?

Comment: Just a suggestion: Perhaps instead of nesting arrays so many levels, you could define a class or struct that does what you are looking to achieve, complete with a method that performs the comparison you're after, get it working, and forget about the implementation details. Your future self will thank you down the line.

Comment: @NicolasMiari Thank you for your suggestion. But I am so noob that I don't really know how to use classes and structures effectively. So I have a vague understanding of you meaning. I hope one day, I'll get to see how to use them correctly in other people's code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only compare [[String]] to String by using the subscript method of the Array to access the inner element.  This would work:

```
func compare() -> Bool {
    let arr: [[String]] = [["foo"]]
    let str: String = "foo"

    guard let innerArr = arr[0] else {
      return false
    }

    guard let element = innerArr[0] else {
      return false
    }

    return element == str
}
```

Comment: The triple '===' is to compare of that are the exact same object not if their value is the same

Comment: Thank you @ChristopherHarris for your answer! I truly appreciate your help.  I am trying to understand it right now. One thing though, why do you have the guard? Is that necessary? Or is it just safer coding?

Comment: Better coding. Swift prefers guard over nested conditionals for readability. Please accept this answer too, thanks!